# Laravel doesn't load relationship for serialized model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple job:

```
class SampleJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, DispatchesJobs;

    private $customer;

    public function __construct(Customer $customer)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->customer = $customer;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        doSomeStuff($customer->currency());
    }
}
```

In the `Customer` model I have relationship for the `country`:

```
clas Customer extends Model
{
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }

    public function currency()
    {
       return $this->country->currency();
    }
}
```

When I dispatch the job via `dispatch(new SampleJob($customer))` I'm getting error in logs:

```
 Call to a member function currency() on null {"code":0,"file":"Customer.php","line":386}
```

A tricky thing here is that if I remove `SerializesModels` trait from the job it will work fine. But I really don't want to do this, because it can lead to unforeseen errors(we have a lot of jobs like this, with much more properties).

So I want just to figure out why this error is happening.

I use `database` driver for jobs.

Laravel 5.8.16. Also, with Laravel 5.6 it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to avoid passing objects when serializing. Passing the customer id would be much better in this case:

```
class SampleJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, DispatchesJobs;

    private $customerId;

    public function __construct(int $customerId)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->customerId = $customerId;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $customer = Customer::find($this->customerId);

        doSomeStuff($customer->currency());
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I know about this. but the project is kind of legacy, and I'm not sure if we have time to refactor all jobs to this approach. So I wanted first to figure out with current error

Answer (score 0):

It is a good thing that Laravel doesn't load relationship for serialized model.
Most of the time it saves you from `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

But using `SerializesModels` is not enough, you should also use a function `->withoutRelations()`

Like this:

```
public function __construct(Sale $sale)
{
    $this->sale         = $sale->withoutRelations();
...
```

BUT if you forget `withoutRelations()` function, the system will `Serialize` your object with links that will be lost after you `UnSerialize` your data back. That would cause the message

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```